# 'Rails' with Activesupport 3.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I'm a new user of Ruby on rails and I try now to create my owen blog to practice this beautiful framework.
So, after I did this commande to start server I got this error , and I thought that from ActiveSupport. 
I need a help :)

The is the message error that I got :

```
 ~/Bureau/blog$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.0.rc2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /home/eayoub/Bureau/blog/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_blog_session'
                              ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/eayoub/Bureau/blog/config/environment.rb:5
    from /home/eayoub/Bureau/blog/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /home/eayoub/Bureau/blog/config.ru:4
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/eayoub/Bureau/blog/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/eayoub/Bureau/blog/config.ru:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are running on Ruby 1.8.7, but the code you have written is only valid in Ruby 1.9.

If possible, I would recommend upgrading up to 1.9.3; that should fix the issue.

If you cannot use Ruby 1.9.3, just change the line from

```
key: '_blog_session'
```

to

```
:key=>'_blog_session'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Ruby 1.9.x? The error is on a line using the new 1.9 hash syntax which is not backwards compatible. Try running ruby --v and seeing what version you're running. If its a 1.8.x you'll need to upgrade Ruby in order to run the latest version of Rails.